# Can I cast a string object passed on command line argument to the actual object?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to cast a command-line passed string object back to actual object?

I want to do the following, but throwing error can't cast.

```
 Button objPro = (Button) sender;
 cProduct cp = (cProduct) objPro.CommandArgument;
```

If no, then why?

This is what the string holds.

```
 cProduct cpObj = (cProduct)e.Row.DataItem;
 Button btnAddProduct = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnAddProduct");
 if (btnAddProduct != null)
 {
     btnAddProduct.CommandArgument = cpObj.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't, because it's a string. It's *not* a `cProduct` (whatever that is - consider following .NET naming conventions and naming it `Product` instead).

Now you could do this if you had a explicit conversion operator in `cProduct` to create an instance from a string.

You haven't really explained what's in the string, or what's in the type - but if your `cProduct` type provides a `ToString` method which contains all the data in a reversible form, then you could easily write a method or a constructor to create the product again:

```
Product product = new Product(objPro.CommandArgument);
```

or maybe:

```
Product product = Product.Parse(objPro.CommandArgument);
```

You'll have to write that constructor/method, of course.

I would strongly recommend using a constructor or method instead of an operator, just to keep your code clearer - it's *very* rarely a good idea to write your own conversion operators.

Comment: this is what string holds

   cProduct cpObj = (cProduct)e.Row.DataItem;
 Button btnAddProduct = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnAddProduct");
            if (btnAddProduct != null) 
            {
                btnAddProduct.CommandArgument = cpObj.ToString();
            }

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: So what does `cProduct.ToString()` return? Do you fundamentally understand the difference between a string and an object of type `cProduct`?

Comment: i see if i make it cProduct.tosting(), it accepts the parameter, but may be i am not getting it fundamentally please elaborate a little if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`CommandArgument` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx). The property is a string, when you assign the a value to the property, you aren't casting some complex type to string, you are setting a string value on the property. Can you cast a string back to your object type anyway, regardless of it being a CommandArgument. I doubt it. If the argument is an int you could try `int.Parse` or similar for other types which have a parse method.